# Dynamodb Schema to fetch related items

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In the schema below, fetching by either of the domain names should return all trusted domain. Is there a way to represent this without creating item for each domain?

For example,

- fetching disney.com will return hulu.com, pixar.com
- fetching hulu.com will return disney.com, pixar.com

[image: Schema]

Comment: Can you give an estimate of a scale of the solution you require?  For example, if the trusted groups are in thousands, you may be better off with using AWS Neptune, a graph database, instead of DynamoDB.

Comment: 90% of the time trusted groups is less than 100. Other 10% it is less than 500.

Comment: why not store everything in 1 record? It will not hit the 400 KB item size limit.

Comment: @VladHolubiev, do you mean remove domainName attribute and store trustedDomains all in one attribute? If so, fetching by a single domain is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on the read and write patterns for your data.  For example, if the relationship sets change once a week and the query for `partitionKey = "disney.com"` happens 100 times a second, the design that you provide in the screenshot provides the maximum possible efficiency, even if you need to drop and recreate the entire table each time  a single trust relationship changes.